# How to use reactstrap via webpack

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, reactstrap

how do I write my config, so I can run successfully?
I do not know what's wrong with my webpack.config.js
or wrong code in other files?

can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

webpack.config.js

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './project/frontend/src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'project/frontend/static/frontend/'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ],
    rules:[
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "django-drf-react-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "weak-key": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.32.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1"
  }
}
```

index.js

```js
import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import App from "./components/app";
```

app.js

```js
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DataProvider from "./DataProvider";
import Table from "./Table";
import Form from "./Form";

import { Button } from 'reactstrap';


class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    console.log('----- in App render -----')
    return(
      <Fragment>
        <DataProvider
          endpoint="api/lead/" 
          render={data => <Table data={data} />} />
        <Form endpoint="api/lead/" />
        <Button color='danger'>Danger!</Button>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<App />, wrapper) : null;
```

the error messages when i npm run dev

```
ERROR in ./project/frontend/src/components/app.js 18:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     console.log('----- in App render -----')
|     return(
>       <Fragment>
|         <DataProvider
|           endpoint="api/lead/" 
 @ ./project/frontend/src/index.js 2:0-35
```

I do not know what's wrong with my webpack.config.js
or wrong code in other files?

Comment: please try to change it for this <React.Fragment>